# Display non-matching records in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables ..Table1 has product_id and product source while table2 has product_id and item.

```
Table1 data
------------
Product_id     Product_source
101              CRM
102              CNT

Table2 data
-----------------
Product_id   item
101           item1
101           item2
```

I want the result as :

```
Product_source   item
CRM               item1
CRM               item2
CNT               null



select product_source , item
from table1 , tabl2
where product_id(+)=tab2.product_id
```

I have tried outer join also but not getting result.
Please assist.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: @dfundako must be Oracle, someone using comma and + for joins (puke).

Answer (score 2):

You need [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
SELECT
    T1.product_source
    ,T2.item
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.product_id = T2.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a left outer join to get this:

```
select product_source, item
from table1
left outer join table2 on table1.product_id = table2.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

**Table1:**

```
Product_id | Product_source |
101        | CRM            |
102        | CNT            |
```

**Table2:**

```
Product_id | item  |
101        | item1 | 
101        | item2 |
```

I want the result as :

```
Product_source | item  | 
CRM            | item1 | 
CRM            | item2 |
CNT            | null  |
```

That being the case, I think you'll want something like:

```
SELECT 
    t1.product_source, t2.item
FROM
    table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON 
    t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```